# How can I reduce the data point size in sns.jointplot()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have the following code drawing a seaborn jointplot. However I don't seem to figure out how to change the size of the data points. I need them to be smaller. I tried keyword `s`, which seems to work for other seaborn plots, but here I get the error:

```
TypeError: regplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 's'
```

Does anyone know how to adjust it?

```
g = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))

g = (sns.jointplot("age", "months_as_customer",
                   data=matrix_ks.to_pandas(), color="green", s=0.2, kind="reg")
                  .set_axis_labels("Age", "Months as Customer",  fontsize=15))

#g = g.annotate(fontsize=18)
plt.title("Joint Density Estime - Age and Months as Customer", pad= 80, fontsize=15)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you defined `kind` as a regplot, you'll need to pass scatter plot parameters via the parameter `scatter_kws`. You can look at the [regplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) to see more details.

```
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.jointplot('total_bill', 'tip', df, kind='reg', scatter_kws={'s': 1})
```

[image]